# Define an Array in Bitbucket Pipelines Deployment Environment Variables

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

In a config.json file that's passed to Auth0's deploy cli, I have the following variable defined in a config.json file:

`"CALLBACKS": ["http://localhost:3000", "https://myapplication.com" ]`

That variable can be overridden by an environment variable if it's present. I'm therefore trying to put the same value in the Deployment environment variables but it's not seeing it as an array.

Anything I should do to make it understand that the value above is not a string?

Comment: It's not possible. If you can programmatically handle the config behind `CALLBACKS` handling, then create a string environment variable with a separator like this `http://localhost:3000,https://myapplication.com` and then split that string using comma `,` to an array and then apply it to your configuration.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I simply declare the array within my pipeline `script` using something like `$declare callbacks ($CALLBACKS)`? Or else, how do I create an array from the comma-separated string?